# App Splash Screen Takes Time After Clearing Cache Data

Tags: android, splash-screen

I am newbie in Android Application Development.My Splash screen takes 19s to load when the app data is cleared from settings.
When App launches the Splash Screen takes 5s.I have no idea why it is taking time
Below is my android AndroidManifest file code:

```
   <activity android:name=".activity.SplashActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@style/SplashTheme"
            >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
```

My Splash Activity is as follows

```
public class SplashActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

public final int SPLASH_DISPLAY_LENGTH=1000;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
   setTheme(R.style.SplashTheme);
   super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
   // setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash);

    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable(){
        @Override
        public void run() {
            /* Create an Intent that will start the Menu-Activity. */
            Intent mainIntent = new Intent(SplashActivity.this,MainActivity.class);
            startActivity(mainIntent);
            finish();
        }
    }, SPLASH_DISPLAY_LENGTH);
}
}
```

My Splash theme is as follows:

```
<style name="SplashTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar">
    <item name="android:windowDisablePreview">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/splash_screen_drawable</item>
</style>
```

My Splash screen drawable is as follows:

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item
        android:drawable="@color/icons"

        />

    <item
        android:left="65dp"
        android:right="65dp">
        <bitmap
            android:gravity="center"
            android:src="@drawable/placeholder_splash"

             />

    </item>
    <item android:drawable="@android:color/transparent"></item>
</layer-list>
```

Comment: Is it happen first time or every time you start the app?

Comment: check out my answer hope this will resolve your issue.

Comment: Are you doing anything special in Application.onCreate() ?

Answer (score 0):

```
public class SplashActivity extends AppCompatActivity {    
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
   super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
   setTheme(R.style.SplashTheme);      

 Thread th = new Thread() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    sleep(1000);
                    Intent i = new Intent(getBaseContext(), MainActivity.class);
                    startActivity(i);                      
                    finish();
                } catch (Exception e) {

                }
            }
        };
        th.start();
}
}
```

Comment: .activity.SplashActivity: +959ms
 I/ActivityManager: Displayed com.ct.linkcardapp/.activity.Home: +474ms (total +884ms)
I/ActivityManager: Displayed com.android.settings/.applications.ManageApplicationsActivity: +349ms
 I/ActivityManager: Displayed com.android.settings/.applications.InstalledAppDetailsTop: +328ms
07-07 13:43:53.599 1630-1690/? I/ActivityManager: Displayed com.ct.linkcardapp/.activity.SplashActivity: +18s926ms
07-07 13:43:55.105 1630-1690/? I/ActivityManager: Displayed com.ct.linkcardapp/.activity.MainActivity: +713ms

Comment: installing again took 19s for splash screen.on app start up

Comment: you mean to say it take 19s to open app not mainActivity from SplashScreen

Comment: for loading splash screen the start time is 19s and from SplashScreen to MainActivity it is not

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with Instant Run feature which takes too much time to load the Application just disable that feature.

> For Windows : File → Settings → Build, Execution, Deployment → Instant
> Run and uncheck Enable Instant Run.
>
> For Mac : Android Studio → Preferences → Build, Execution, Deployment → Instant
> Run and uncheck Enable Instant Run.

See the Below Screenshot and uncheck that two options. After that uninstall the application and then run the project again.

[image]